# How to read data from json file and use it to show in view component in react native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I need to show "Top rated" in separate FlatList and the content which is courses inside it like how udemy shows its content. But I am new to react native never made such an app so I don't know how to fetch the data from the JSON file and then show it like this.

json file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9J34syhsly7S43OzGar4RQN3d6g_yZn/view?usp=sharing

I have also attached the UI images to explain what I am trying to say and how I wanted to show my json data.

[image]

```
const Data = require("../Data/static_courses_data.json");
const CategoriesScreen = (props) => {
  const renderGridItem = (itemData) => {
    return (
      <CategoryGrid
        title={itemData.item["Title"]}
        imgUrl={itemData.item["image-url"]}
        onSelect={}
      ></CategoryGrid>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList data={Data} renderItem={renderGridItem} numColumns={2} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I have also tried like this but it gives me an error saying `Object is not a constructor(evaluating 'new_meal.default)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By directly importing your .json file you can do the following, however the items are not separated by categories for your specific case. I just took all the titles for an example.

First you use `Object.keys` to get all the keys from your `Top Rated` and then use `Object.values` to get their values

This link might be helpful: https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/76-converting-object-to-array/

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';

import data from './data.json';

const App = () => {
  const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState([]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredItems([]);
    setCategories(Object.keys(data['Top Rated']));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (categories) {
      categories.map(category => {
        setFilteredItems(prevState => [
          ...prevState,
          Object.values(
            data['Top Rated'][`${category}`].map(item => `${item.Title}\n`),
          ),
        ]);
      });
    }
  }, [categories]);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
        data={filteredItems}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{`${item}\n`}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: In this, you are mapping only "Title" in `filteredItems`, and in the FlatList, I can only access Title so how can I map all object values in `filteredItems` and access it like this `item.Title`, `item.['avg-rating']`, `item.url`?

Comment: Can I use push() or some other function to combine after mapping all objects using the same logic as you did for just Title?

Comment: You can use the previous method to map the categories and call the following to directly access the items:

`const App = () => {
  const renderByCategory = category => (
    <Text>
      {Object.values(data['Top Rated'][category].map(item => item.Title))}
    </Text>
  );

  return <View style={{flex: 1}}>{renderByCategory('Data Science')}</View>;
};`

Answer (score 1):

Make it a JS file and export the data like so:

**data.js**

```
const data = [
  { some: "data" }, 
  { other: "data" },
  ...
  ...
];

export default data;
```

Then import it where you'd like to use it, like any other JS file.

**SomeReactNativeComponent.js**

```
import data from './path/to/data.js'
// ... other imports

const SomeReactNativeComponent = ( props ) => {
...

// component functions

...

}
```

EDIT, OP's requested method:

```
fetch("./path/to/static_courses_data.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: Please see the code I have added. I tried this also.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm suggesting is exporting the JSON file as a JavaScript object. So your JSON file will no longer be `static_courses_data.json` it would be `static_courses_data.js` and it would follow the form of the first snippet in my answer, or something similar to it.

Comment: @HarshMishra see the edit to my answer for more specific instructions.

Comment: But, Isn't possible to fetch the data locally from a JSON file without converting it into a js file?

Comment: Also, Still getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: See edit, I've included a snippet on using Fetch API with a JSON file source.

Comment: Also, you should use a default import if you're going to try my previously suggested method. That is the source of the error you added to your question.